# Loading another component instead of root-app-component

Tags: html, angular, routes

When we use angular routing,can another component be loaded in the main HTML page instead of root-app component according to the given route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`element on your root-app. i think it will works.

Answer (score 3):

You can change default page from index.html to different page in angular.json.  You could also change the selector in index.html from root-app to any other component. You can also use a router outlet

Comment: Give practical working code to do all those things, instead of you can do this or that.